# Are Euler angle figures wrong?

Tags: rotations

In the typical Euler angle figure one sees three angles represented as turns along three orthogonal axis. If I understand correctly, Euler angles parameterize a rotation with an order. Meaning that once the first rotation is done (say for Roll) then the second one  won't be along any of the axis typically shown in the figures. Is this correct or I'm missing something?

[image: Typical Euler angles figure]

Answer (score 3):

Say we apply first roll, then pitch, then yaw. (I don't know whether that's conventional, but that's not important.)

After applying, say, $5^\circ$ roll, it is time to apply pitch. We now have a choice to make: Do we apply pitch around the old, horizontal $y$-axis ("world axis"), or the new one that's $5^\circ$ slanted ("local / body axis")? It doesn't really matter which one we pick, but we have to pick one. Say we apply it to the new $y$-axis. Then we apply yaw, and to be consistent we apply it to the new $z$-axis.

Here is a little bit of magic for you: this gives the *exact same end result* as applying each of them in the reverse order and choosing to apply it to the old axes.

So in the end, there is no reason to labor too much over whether to use the new or the old axes. Which is to say, don't think too hard about whether you want the red lines in your figure to follow the anatomy of the plane or not. Because choosing which of the six orders to apply roll, pitch and yaw will swallow that choice anyways. So just pick one of the two. But be consistent, please. Don't use the old $y$-axis but the new $z$-axis.

Comment: Some people use the terms "body axis" and "world axis" to describe the distinction between whether you apply rotations to the "old" axes or the "new" axes.

Comment: @DavidK Right you are. I added those terms.